# Curve to Mesh for open curves

Tags: geometry-nodes, curve-modifier

I have an .obj file that I load that represents a curve

```
1 v x1 y1 z1
2 v x2 y2 z2
3 v x3 y3 z3
...
n v xn yn zn
f 1 2 3 ... n
```

Then I can click my mesh and do `convert to curve` and I get a nice closed curve. However, I do not want my curve to be closed. I want it to start at `v1` and end at `vn` without going back to `v1`. How can I do this?  Ideally, I would like to do it with a geometry node starting from the Mesh to curve modifier.

Comment: in edit mode you could set the curve to non Cyclic

Comment: @shmuel that did it for me!

Answer (score 2):

Your question is a bit confusing. You say you do not want the curve to be open, you want it to start at `v1` and end at `vn` without going back to `v1`. But that is an open curve - when it is not cyclic, i.e. not going back to `vn`.

I'm also not sure what exactly you are doing differently when converting a mesh to a curve, because in my Blender the curve is by default non-cyclic. If I want a closed curve, I have to manually set it to *Cyclic U* in the curve's *Data Properties* under *Active Spline*. There you can turn it off as well of course. The same setting can be toggled between cyclic and non-cyclic in the viewport in *Edit Mode* with the shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

[image: active spline cyclic]

However, since you mention *Geometry Nodes*, you can do all this there as well, you do not have to convert it to a curve beforehand - just leave it as a mesh object and add a *Geometry Nodes* modifier to it.

In the nodetree then you can convert the mesh to a curve with the *Mesh to Curve* modifier. This should also by default be a non-cyclic curve. If for some reason it is cyclic, you can add a *Set Spline Cyclic* node after the *Mesh to Curve* and uncheck *Cyclic*.

[image: gn set spline cyclic]

The reason why I would not convert the mesh to a curve object directly outside of *Geometry Nodes* is the following: first of all, you could then use the *Geometry Nodes* nodetree on every mesh object without having to convert it to curve manually, and secondly depending on what you want to do with it afterwards, some things that need a mesh object instead of a curve object do not work.

For example, if you have the *Geometry Nodes* modifier on a curve object, no matter how much meshes you generate inside the nodetree, you cannot use some of the other modifiers on a curve object, almost none of the modifiers in the categories *Edit* or *Physics* and from *Generate* and *Deform* there are some missing as well.

You also cannot simply apply the *Geometry Nodes* modifier on a curve object by hovering over it and pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> or choosing *Apply* from the modifier menu. This will throw an error: *"Cannot apply constructive modifiers on curve. Convert curve to mesh in order to apply."* (Even if the output would have been a curve, not a mesh.) But beware, if you now convert the curve to a mesh, other than with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> now **all** modifiers get applied, even if you had *Bevel* or *Subdivision Surface* etc. after the *Geometry Nodes* and wanted to keep them.

But if you want the object to stay a curve and not convert it into a mesh, I would do it without *Geometry Nodes*. Because if you ever want to apply the *Geometry Nodes* modifier, the only result that will be kept after applying is mesh data, so if you only have a curve in there applying will not work either.